# How to organize the form elements horizontally in SAP workflow form designer

Tags: workflow, sap-business-technology-platform, form-designer

I'm trying to build a search page using SAP workflow's form designer where the users can search an insurance program by one of three select options (drop downs) by Program Name or by Program year or by Program status. And the requirement is to place the three drop downs horizontally side by side in the same line. This will be followed by two buttons on next line Search and Create New Program. But instead of getting the form elements in desired fashion all the elements are coming vertically stacked one under the other.

[image]

Whereas the required wireframe is as follows:

[image]

I'm new to SAP Workflow so if anyone can help me out on this that will be really appreciated.

Comment: By using a [section](https://help.sap.com/docs/Advanced_Workflow/b7cb13f8b6a04157a722ad9ddfde4a28/72b599c47c231014a804993ce4041860.html#section) with 3 columns? (link: Advanced Workflow > Workflow > Workflow for Administrators > Form Designer > UI Tab > Section)